# Camera Application freezes on Juno but not Loki

Tags: applications, release-juno, camera

So for some reason, the Camera application in Juno is not initializing my webcam and then freezes after a few seconds.

When ran in the terminal, the following message appears:

**(io.elementary.camera:9327): Clutter-Gst-WARNING **: 22:00:44.437: Internal data stream error.**

Any other video application has no issue opening the video device.

This was not an issue in Loki.

Here's the information on my Camera:

**description: Video
product: Integrated_Webcam_HD
vendor: CN06307G7248761BE247A03
physical id: 4
bus info: usb@1:4
version: 57.28
capabilities: usb-2.00
configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s**

Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar issue: `$ io.elementary.camera 
(io.elementary.camera:6083): Clutter-Gst-WARNING **: 13:32:08.090: Internal data stream error.` while the webcam was working fine in Loki.

Comment: Also: "cheese" the gnome camera application is working fine. Install it through `sudo apt-get install cheese`

Answer (score 1):

This issue is a problem with the Juno OS, which requires a bug to be submitted for a fix. However, you should install a third-party webcam application to use the camera. One of the best third-party camera applications for Juno OS is Cheese.